# Is there any way to clear the change made using instances of class in c#.for example

Tags: c#

Is it possible to clear(erase) the changes made to an array by using its reference object in another class in c#?

Comment: It's impossible. You have to store copy of original array. Or log changes which you are doing

Comment: Thank you! Sergey Berezovskiy